# If |x|< 1/2 then the polynomial $1 + \frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}$ aproximates the value of $\sqrt{1+x}$ with an error minor of $\frac{1}{2}|x^3|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

Demonstrate that if $|x|< 1/2$ then the polynomial $1 + \frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}$ aproximates the value of $\sqrt{1+x}$ with an error minor of $\frac{1}{2}|x^3|$.

I've done the MacLaurin polinomial of $\sqrt{1+x}$ until degree $2$ that is $1 + \frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}$. I know how to calculate the error depending on the grade of the polynomial but not how to calculate it depending on the value of $x$. I also tried to use the Lagrange reminder.

Comment: Hint: The Lagrange remainder is $$
\frac{1}{{8(1 + \xi )^{5/2} }}\frac{{x^3 }}{2}
$$ with $|\xi|\le|x|<1/2$. You can bound this further by taking $\xi=-1/2$.

Comment: See: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html